# Remove matching items from object

Tags: php

I have an object named $list that is formatted like the following

```
{"name":"cats","title":"Cats"},{"name":"dogs","title":"Dogs"},{"name":"rabbits","title":"Hares"}
```

I have a second object named $list2 formatted like the following:

```
{"title":"Cats","name":"cats"},{"title":"Dogs","name":"dogs"},{"title":"Pigs","name":"pigs"},{"title":"Funny","name":"funny"},{"title":"Pictures","name":"pictures"},{"title":"Finance","name":"finance"},{"title":"Cars","name":"cars"},
```

I would like to go through $list and check if it is in $list2.  If the name item is in $list2's name items then I would like to remove it from $list.  Expected result in this case would be

```
{"name":"rabbits","title":"Hares"}
```

I have tried a few different looping techniques but I cannot seem to get it to match up correctly.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring ig out. Did you have a question?

Comment: So wait, if the title matches you don't want it removed? Only if the name is the same on both sides?

Comment: Grumpy, I want to remove the name and title, if the name matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the built-in `array_udiff()` function. It finds the difference in the arrays with a function that you provide.

```
$result = array_udiff($list1, $list2, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

So this would return all objects that are not in `$list2` but are in `$list1`. I'm assuming the name determines uniqueness.